# Criar pasta na memoria interna do dispositivo e exibir mensagem após gravação

Tags: java, android

Estou com dois problemas.

O `Toast` no meu método me retorna o seguinte erro:

> The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is
>   not applicable for the arguments (GerarRelatorio, String, int)

Como exibir uma mensagem padrão de erro? Como por exemplo "*Documento não criado*".

Para criar a pasta estou usando esse código, testei no emulador e não aconteceu nada, criando o arquivo PDF na pasta Documents com essa linha da certo:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
```

Porem só na *API 19*, por isso queria criar a pasta e checar se ela existe ou não, para eu poder usar no *Android 4.0* em diante.

```
public void CriarRelatorio(ClienteClass objCliente, EquipamentoClass objEquipamento, ServicoClass objServico, PecasClass objPecas){
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Relatorios");

        if(!direct.exists()) {
             if(direct.mkdir()); //se não existir o diretorio e criado
        }

        File pdffile = new File(direct, "RelatorioTeste.pdf");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdffile));
        document.open();
        addMetaData(document);
        addTituloRelatorio(document);
        addConteudo(document);
        document.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Arquivo criado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia verificar se é lançada alguma exceção naquele bloco catch? Caso seja, poste o stacktrace.

Comment: Sua classe `GerarRelatorio` é uma `Activity` ou `Fragment`?

Comment: Na verdade eu tinha criado só uma classe publica com um método Gerar Relatório, mas no meu exemplo aqui que fiz, o método esta dentro de uma activity mesmo, achei que daria para chamar o método de criar o PDF pela activity principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim, aqui funciona em todas API.

```
  private File getDirFromSDCard() {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsoluteFile();
            File dir = new File(sdcard, "APP_NAME" + File.separator + "PASTA_1");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            return dir;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: muio boa a dia mas a linha
`private File getDirFromSDCard()`
me retorna isso
`Syntax error on token "File", @ expected`

Comment: Qual a linha ? lembre-se que vc tem "APP_NAME" e o nome do seu aplicativo e "PASTA_1" nome da pasta que você vai guardar os arquivos.